# Difference between arg: number as function parameters, and Number(arg)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Following a NestJS tutorial, I encountered something that drew my attention (coming from a `service.ts` file):

```
public async putCarById(id: number, property_name: string, property_value: string)// : Promise<any>
    {
        console.log(id);        // gives provided number, for example, 1
        const carId = Number(id); 
        console.log(typeof (id)); // will output "string" - why ?
        console.log(typeof (carId)); // will output "number" -- which I understand

(...)
```

I could not find why it was necessary to do the "cast" while id was supposed to be received as a number.

Comment: Presumably the types are a lie; _at runtime_ it's getting a string, so the function interface should reflect that. The compiler can only be helpful if given accurate information - if you were expecting a TypeScript type at compile time to cause any kind of JavaScript casting or conversion at runtime (by which time all type metadata has been erased), that's a fundamental misunderstanding of what's happening.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have absolutely no problem admitting I totally misunderstand what is happening - and I'll dig into what you've just said, thanks sir !